# Nullable type and if issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, nullable

Here is simplest piece of code

```
Dim testInvoiceDate As DateTime? = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nothing),
                                      Nothing,
                                      New DateTime(2018, 3, 20))
```

Why variable `testInvoiceDate` is not `Nothing` , but `#1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#` ?!
That is very weird !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `If`-statement will return the same datatype for both cases.

Because the return-type in the `False`-case is `DateTime`, the return-type is the `DateTime`-default-value for the `True`-case.

Default for `DateTime` is `DateTime.MinValue` which is `#1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#`.

This will work as expected:

```
Dim testInvoiceDate As DateTime? = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nothing),
                                      Nothing,
                                      New DateTime?(New Date(2018, 3, 20)))
```

Comment: Or the `Nothing` can be `CType(Nothing, DateTime?)` to also get the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

That compiles in VB.NET(as opposed to C#) because here `Nothing` has multiple meanings.

1. `null`
2. default value for that type

In this case the compiler uses the second option since there is otherwise no implicit conversion between the `DateTime` and `Nothing`(in the meaning of `null`).

The default value of `DateTime`(a `Structure` which is a value type) is `#1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM#`

You could use this to get a `Nullable(Of DateTime)`:

```
Dim testInvoiceDate As DateTime? = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nothing), New Nullable(Of Date), New DateTime(2018, 3, 20))
```

or use an `If`:

```
Dim testInvoiceDate As DateTime? = Nothing
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Nothing) Then testInvoiceDate = New DateTime(2018, 3, 20)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Nothing` in VB.Net is the equivalent of `default(T)` in C#: the default value for the given type.

- For value types, this is essentially the equivalent of 'zero': `0` for `Integer`, `False` for `Boolean`, `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`, ...
- For reference types, it is the `null` value (a reference that refers to, well, nothing).

Asigning `Nothing` to a `DateTime` therefore is the same as assigning it `DateTime.MinValue`

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're using the 3-argument form of `If()`. It will try to return the same type based on parameters 2 and 3, so the Nothing in parameter 2 gets converted to a DateTime (and you get DateTime.MinValue).

If you use the 2-argument form, it applies null-coalescing, i.e. when the first argument (which must be an Object or a nullable type) is `Nothing`, it returns the second argument, otherwise it returns the first argument.

If you use
`Dim foo As DateTime? = If(Nothing, new DateTime(2018, 3, 20))` you will get the expected value.