# Assigning textbox text with property of nullable datatype

Tags: vb.net, controls, nullable

For some reason I am having an error when I am trying to assign a property of nullable decimal data type to a textbox text.

For example I have this Product class:

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property ProductId As Integer
    Public Property ProductName As String
    Public Property [Variant] As String
    Public Property PackSize As Decimal?
End Class
```

and an instance of a `Product` has a `[Variant]` value of `Nothing` and a `PackSize` value of `Nothing`.

When I try to assign the `[Variant]` value to a text box like this:

```
VariantTextBox.Text = mProduct.[Variant]
```

it works fine.

But when I try to assign the `PackSize` value to a text box like this:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize
```

it throws an exception with this message:

> Nullable object must have a value.

I don't understand why this happens when I could do this:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = Nothing
```

with no errors whatsoever.

I tried other ways of doing things like:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize IsNot Nothing, mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize.HasValue, mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)
```

but they all throw the same error.

However, when I tweak them a little like these:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize, "")
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize IsNot Nothing, mProduct.PackSize, "")
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize.HasValue, mProduct.PackSize, "")
```

they weirdly work fine.

Ultimately, I really don't like doing long `If` statements just to get the value of a nullable data type property so I just went with this:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize?.ToString
```

I hope someone could explain to me the error I am encountering.
Thanks!

Comment: The differences between the `If` operator actually came up yesterday in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385641/nullable-type-and-if-issue)

Comment: Why is this tagged `c#` when it's obviously `VB.Net`? Either use `Option strict` in all your projects or just switch to c#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is type `String` so the only thing that can be assigned to it is a `String`. If you have `Option Strict Off` and assign something other than a `String` then the system will implicitly call `ToString` on it.  That means that this:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize
```

is basically the same as this:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize.Value.ToString()
```

and it should be obvious why you get the error message you do when `mProduct.PackSize` is `Nothing`.

All of these:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize IsNot Nothing, mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)
PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize.HasValue, mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)
```

fail to work because the `If` operators are basically generic, in that the two values returned MUST be the same type.  As a result, all of your `Nothing` return values are implicitly converted to `Decimal?` values and you end up with that having to be implicitly converted to a `String` in exactly the same way with exactly the same result.

The code you ended up with:

```
PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize?.ToString
```

is the correct code because you are explicitly converting something that is not a `String` to a `String` in order to assign it to a `String` property.  That's exactly what you should be doing and exactly what you would have to do if you had `Option Strict On`, which you ABSOLUTELY should do.

Any VB.NET developer that has `Option Strict Off` by default is either a beginner who doesn't know any better or a bad developer. Turn it `On` now in your project properties and also in your IDE options, so that it is `On` by default in all future projects.  You should only turn it `Off` when you specifically need late-binding and, even then, only in partial class files that contain only the specific code that requires late-binding.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the well thought out explanation unlike those other people with not so helpful condescending responses. I was coming from a long-time experience with C# and ended up with VB because of corporate "policy". Didn't know that strict option before. Thanks again!

Comment: Many VB.NET developers lament that `Option Strict` is `Off` by default. I've not heard an official explanation but most people I've spoken to agree that it was done to make VB.NET as much like VB6 as possible for the beginner. It means that genuine beginners can write code without thinking to hard about types. It also means that VB6 developers won't get pissed off at having to make hundreds of small changes to their upgraded code.

Comment: Note that your original code (`PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize`) would have failed to even compile in C# and you'd have had to use the same final code anyway. Having `Option Strict On` means that issues like this are headed off at compile time instead of showing up at run time, just as happens with C#.

Comment: Yes, I am aware `PackSizeTextBox.Text = mProduct.PackSize` will not work in C# but I was just trying to enjoy the implicitness of VB before realizing this conundrum. Should have just stuck with the strictness of C#.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the default setting for `Option Strict`, when creating a new project, is settable in the **Visual Studio > Options > Projects and Solutions > VB Defaults** screen.  The default for the other options like `Explicit` and `Infer` can be altered there as well.  That won't help you if a colleague creates a new VB project, and they haven't fixed their defaults, but it at least makes it easier if you set your own the way you want.

Comment: That's what I was thinking myself, but having spent the last 6 years in c# and away from vb.net, I needed to check myself. Regarding the **" the If operators are basically generic, in that the two values returned MUST be the same type."** I couldn't find documentation for that. Would you mind linking or quoting the documentation on that?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I'm not sure that it is documented but it can be determined through usage. Any time you use an `If` operator and mouse over it, you can see that it has a return type that is the most-derived base type of the two return values. With `Option Strict On`, that type cannot be inferred to be `Object`. If you mouse over the `If` operator in a line like `PackSizeTextBox.Text = If(mProduct.PackSize, Nothing)`, you can see that the return type is `Decimal?` as the type of `Nothing` is inferred from the other return value.

Comment: That's what I thought. In c# documentation, the (equivalent) `?:` operator documentation states : *"Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other."* So I thought I might have just missed it. Thanks anyway.