# VB.NET If statement does something strange with Nullable Enum Type

Tags: vb.net, enums, nullable, value-type

I just ran into the following behavior that's so strange that I can't figure out how it could be correct.

Suppose I have an Enum like;

```
Enum MyEnum
  ...
End Enum
```

and a routine that returns a nullable value of that enum type. It's nullable because my logic checks a certain string to see if it contains a value. If it does, I want to map it to that enum, and if it doesn't, I return Nothing to signal that there was no value:

```
    Shared ReadOnly Property Phase As MyEnum?
        Get
            syntax 1 --> 
            Return If(myString.IsNotBlank, myString.ToEnum(Of MyEnum), Nothing) 

            syntax 2 --> 
            If myString.IsNotBlank Then
                Return myString.ToEnum(Of MyEnum)
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If

        End Get
    End Property
```

I would have thought that the two syntaxes were identical, but they are not. Syntax #2 does what I want. But syntax #1 does something different. If the value is blank, instead of returning Nothing, that is, a `Nullable(Of MyEnum)` with HasValue = False, it returns an empty Enum with value 0, whether or not `MyEnum` has a member with value 0.

What's going on here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nullable type and if issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385641/nullable-type-and-if-issue)

Comment: The If method need to figure out the return value and none of your returned value is a nullable so it just returns the enum.