# Issue With .NET Ternary Operator and Type Conversions

Tags: vb.net, ternary-operator

I have a ternary expression that checks to see if an `Object` is `DBNull.Value` and returns `Nothing` if `True` else if `False` returns the value converted to  the `Date` type of that `Object`. However, for some strange reason my nullable `DateTime` variable that is being set by the ternary expression is mysteriously set to `'1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM'` even though `Object` is most certainly a `DBNull.Value`. Can anyone else reproduce this behavior? If so, why does it happen?

The strange part is that I've changed this expression to regular old if and else blocks and I don't get this behavior at all. So, it has to be something to do with the ternary statement.

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DateColumn", GetType(String)))
    dt.Rows.Add()
    Dim testDate = dt(0).Item(0)
    Dim setDate As DateTime? = Nothing
    'Doesn't work
    setDate = If(testDate Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, CDate(testDate))
    'Works
    'If testDate Is DBNull.Value Then
    '    setDate = Nothing
    'Else
    '    setDate = CDate(testDate)
    'End If
    'Also works
    'setDate = If(testDate Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, CType(testDate, DateTime?))
    'This works too
    'setDate = If(testDate Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, testDate)
    'Working
    'setDate = IIf(testDate Is DBNull.Value, Nothing, testDate)
    If setDate IsNot Nothing Then
        Console.WriteLine("Why does setDate = '" & setDate.ToString & "' ?!")
    End If
    Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

End Module
```

I would like to use the ternary statement because it is less code.

Comment: I think ternary operator in VB is IIF, not IF. Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: You can use both, but the issue in this particular example with IIF is that both the true and false expressions are evaluated which would throw an exception if `testDate` is `DBNull.Value`. Actually, if I remove the call to `CDate` both work as intended.

Comment: A basic requirement is that the false and true parts must have the same type so that the expression type is unambiguous.  That's nailed down for CDate(), it cannot do anything but turn Nothing into a Date as well.  That's possible, as you found out.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Because I am using CDate the return type of the ternary expression will always be of the type `Date` which isn't nullable. Is this correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nullable type and if issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385641/nullable-type-and-if-issue)

Comment: @CarlosAdrián Exactly the opposite.  `IIf` is a legacy function, `If` is the ternary operator (among other uses).  Because `IIf` is a function, it evaluates *all* of its arguments (whereas the ternary operator only evaluates the branch that it needs to take), and because it is for legacy support, its argument and return types are `Object` meaning that conversion issues will throw an exception at runtime rather than failing to compile.

Comment: @HansPassant It should perhaps be noted that the true meaning of `Nothing` is "default value for type", not null, per a recent blog post by Anthony Green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that VB infers the return type of the `If` operator to be a `Date` because that is what CDate returns. The `Nothing` keyword can be converted to a non-nullable `Date` object because Nothing also means "default" in VB, and the default value of a Date is `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`. To fix this you have to make sure at least one of the parameters is explicitely a `DateTime?`.

For example, this would work:

```
setDate = If(testDate Is DBNull.Value, New DateTime?, CDate(testDate))
```

Comment: Thank you, I wouldn't have thought of doing this. I feel like I learned something today.